# missing 'android project'

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

I have reformatted my computer. When I installed eclipse, android avd and the SDK I am now missing the options. To make an android program. I can make an android application program. That's the closest option I have. Is there a big difference in the two? Has anyone ran into this problem before?
Much thanks!

Comment: ya 2 days before i faced the same problem..Again i  have installed every thing

Comment: did you define the Android SDK in Eclipse? did you try opening a general project and then choosing Android?

Comment: Yes and then no. I will try that when I get home

Answer (score 0):

I think your Android Plugin has been removed from the eclipse.

- Go to Help menu and select "Install New Software"
- Type the URL `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` in the textbox
- Select the Android Plugin Components and install them.

Comment: Thanks all for the help but, it was not the solution. Still have not found one. Is the android applicaton project very differant from an android project??

Comment: No luck as of now. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: means you are still in same position ?

Comment: i strongly believe that you are only missing one or two of the android plugin into your eclipse, this is the reason that your are not getting Android option in your eclipse, as you mentioned in the question.